# flash notice persisting in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a controller with an update method that updates the model attribute, sets a flash notice for the user if successful and then renders the edit page again. The next link I click on the same flash notice pops up a second time when it loads/renders the page. What's going on? How do I get the flash[:notice] to show up only once? Why is it persisting into the next response?

controller:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @resource.update_attributes(params[:resource])
      flash[:notice] = "Resource successfully updated"
      format.html{ render :action => "edit" }
    else
      format.html{ render :action => "edit" }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want the flash notification to be displayed immediately, use `flash.now[:notice]` instead of `flash[:notice]`. The default behavior is to save the flash until the subsequent request is processed, where the `now` version will clear it after the current request is finished.

Comment: Thanks. This answer explains the cause of the behavior I was asking about.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using `render` method after a successful edition. Instead try using `redirect_to`:

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @resource.update_attributes(params[:resource])
        flash[:notice] = "Resource successfully updated"
        format.html{ redirect_to :action => edit, :id => @resource }
    else
        format.html{ render :action => "edit" }
    end
end
```

Check [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect_to) for more information about the differences between those two methods.

Comment: I understand the differences between render/redirect, and it basically seemed more direct to render the template view I wanted in this case, rather than redirecting. (doesn't require a roundtrip to the browser, and there's no special state necessary for the view I want). So I'm wondering about your "should not" above. Is it just a matter of potentially repeating yourself (or causing errors) if in the future the edit action does wind up needing special state? (ala the books example in your link) Or are there other considerations?

Comment: @Bee One of the things that can cause some problems is, for example, adding the page to favorites. One would expect that if you bookmark a page that says "This is an edit page" when you visit it you get the edit page. In this case you get the show page. You can also try refreshing the pages and see what you get. I remember reading a good article about this issue, but I can't find it now. I'll link it in my comments when I find it.

Comment: Thanks for responding @maro! I hadn't thought of the consideration about bookmarking and I'll probably change to redirect in my app because of it. However, I am going to accept @tadman's answer because it directly answers the question asked and explains the behavior that was resulting from my code.